# Physics based animations for NON Game developer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I have worked of couple of iOS apps using Objective-C and XCode. Most of my apps are children's interactive books, completely written in Objective-C and all interactive animations are UIView based. In my next book, I would like to add some Physics based animations. What are my best options? I have never worked on Cocos2D or used any other physics based animations engines. I recently started reading about Chipmunk physics based animation engine. Should I be using Chipmunk along with Objective-C for achieving physics based animations or consider switching to Cocos2D? I am not considering game development at the moment. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions/advice.

Thanks,
Ramesh.

Comment: Chipmunk has nothing to do with cocos2d, other than cocos2d distributing a version of chipmunk. You can just as well add chipmunk to your existing project and experiment. Regardless, it's not possible to give advice because both options are reasonable and in the end choosing either one is largely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chipmunk without Cocos2d as you can see from its examples. 
But i would recommend using Cocos2d along with Chipmunk. Cocos2d comes with a project template with Chipmunk, there are a lot of examples and all.
We did an [interactive book](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-phantom-clickerist/id465630229?mt=8) with Cocos2d and Chipmunk with a lot of physics interactions and it works just great.